# the for loop shows NA for every iteration except for the last one

Tags: r, for-loop, vector, output

I wanted to run a t.test on every row in the matrix I have constructed. Then I tried to pull out the values for the confidence intervals and save them in separate vectors with one output per each iteration. However, after I run the code I get L1=NA NA NA....8.155677. I would be greatful if you could point out the mistakes.

(I understand there are numerous ways to write this code cleaner but, I tried to write it step-by-step.)

```
set.seed(1234)

n= 24 # sample size or a number of RV's

N=100 # number of exrtractions or a number of sums for each rv

X=rnorm(N*n, 9, 1.5 ) # generate rv's

XMat=matrix(X,nrow=N)
```

#Problem Part:

```
L1=c()

L2=c()

for(i in N)
{
   s=XMat[i,1:n]
   K=t.test(s,conf.level=0.95)
   M=K$conf.int
   l1=M[1]
   l2=M[2]
   L1[i]=l1
   L2[i]=l2
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the loop control to:

```
for (i in seq(N))
```

You are running the loop for a single value of `i` in your code.

Comment: OH.. it was that simple. Thank you so much! I've been staring at it for an hour without any clue)))